# What is the genre of "Cocaine" by Eric Clapton?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I am very much in love with the music [*Cocaine* by Eric Clapton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVOuRQPPdoo). What is the genre of this song? If possible suggest me some more songs like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd qualify that by labeling this as blues-rock. "Cocaine" is a modified 12-bar blues. If you search for blues albums from the 1970s and 1980s, you'll find plenty there. Try Stevie Ray Vaughan, Robert Cray, Buddy Guy, and even the late B.B. King. Guys who sound like Clapton would be more those who came up in the UK in the 1960s, like Rory Gallagher and Jeff Beck.

Comment: Thanks for input. It was very much helpful and I will start listening to everyone of them.

Answer (score 1):

The genre is called "rock music". The song was written by J. J. Cale. Look for more recordings of songs that he wrote, and look for more rock songs from the late 1970s. Look for more songs recorded by Eric Clapton from the late 1970s.

Comment: Rock is too large a genre to be helpful to the OP, IMHO.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I agree, way too much blues influence to only be classified as "rock music".  Although classic rock radio will often group it with other "rock music" (as well as more traditional blues-rock).